# How to return value from an API call in javascript to a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I cant seem to return the value of this API call in javascript to my react component. I have a java script file that calls an API. In the js file, results are returned but when I call the js function in useEffect in my react component, it returns undefined.

```
export function ordersData() {

    const partner_code = localStorage.getItem('partner_code')

    let items = []
    let data = []
    let isLoaded = false
    let error = ''

    fetch('xxxxxxxxxxxx' + process.env.REACT_API)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            for (let instance in result['docs']) {
                let payload = (result['docs'][instance])

                payload.id = instance

                payload.timestamp = shortMonthYear(payload.timestamp)

                data.push(payload)
            }

            items = data.reverse()

        }, (err) => {
            isLoaded(true)
            error(err)
        })
}
```

Here is my rect component

export default function OrdersChart() {

```
const [payload, setPayload]  = useState([])
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setPayload = ordersData()
    console.log(payload)
}, [])
```

........

The variable payload is empty

Comment: the API calls are asyncronous. To get value you should use .then on the Promise. So it'll be `ordersData().then(payload => console.log(payload))`. Also you should return fetch from ordersData function.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use React hooks for API calls and store the data. You can use `useEffect` hooks to call the API  and use `useState` for storing data in the state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function useFetchData() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setData(responseJson.results);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return { loading, data };
}

function App() {
  const { loading, data } = useFetchData();
   
  if(loading){
   return <p>Loading... </p>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div>{item.name.first}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way I found was this

Change parent component to this

```
useEffect(() => {
   newFunctionName();
}, [])

async function newFunctionName(){
   const response = await ordersData();
   console.log(response)
   // you can then set all your states directly in here
}
```

Change api call component to this.

```
export default async function ordersData() {
    try{
        const res = await fetch('xxxxxxxxxxxx' + process.env.REACT_API)
        return res
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
      return(err)
    }
}
```

Now you have the response in the parent component and can set states from there instead.

Answer (score 1):

You dont return anything in this function. You just push payload value in data, that a local variable. You can use state and set value by setState.